# I there way to intercept the API4 call made for SearchDisplay run

Tags: searchkit, search-builder

We are building a search form using a search kit. Based on saved search name

```
    [
      [
        "SearchDisplay",
        "run",
        {
          "return": "page:1",
          "savedSearch": "Member_Player_Search",
          "display": "Table",
          "sort": [
            [
              "sort_name",
              "ASC"
            ]
          ],
          "limit": 50,
          "seed": 1682511192645,
          "filters": {
            "last_name": "test",
            "first_name": "user"
          },
          "afform": "afsearchPlayerSearch"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Example :

```
if (!empty($filter['last_name'])) {
  $filter['custom_123'] = 1;
}
// custom_123 is boolean field of Yes/No.
```

If the last name is not empty in the filter then I want to add an additional filter before making a call to contact api. (through hook)

Is this feasible ?

I tried using the search kit tool **fx** `if/else` functionality but was not able to figure it out in the UI to make the same condition.

Drupal 9, CiviCRM 5.57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [apiWrapper hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_apiWrappers/) can do this (it's deprecated, but scroll down to see how to implement it the new way)